# TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. React.js Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im coding a navigation bar, button should change false to true  and true to false for display a navigation menu, but when i click on it throws `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

NavBar.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./navbar.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faBars } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const NavBar = (props) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <span className="navbar__home">Iván Méndez</span>
      <span className="navbar__link">Acerca de mí</span>
      <span className="navbar__link">Proyectos</span>
      <span className="navbar__link">Habilidades</span>
      <span className="navbar__link">Contactacme</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => setToggle((toggle = !toggle))}
        className="navbar__toggler"
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Chrome throws this:

```
  13 | <span className="navbar__link">Habilidades</span>
  14 | <span className="navbar__link">Contactacme</span>
  15 | <button
> 16 |   onClick={() => setToggle(toggle = !toggle)}
     | ^  17 |   className="navbar__toggler"
  18 | >
  19 |   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
```

Ive Been reading react docs again and again but im misunderstanding somethings

Comment: You probably meant to use arrow `=>` instead of an assignment operator: `setToggle(toggle = !toggle)` ----> `setToggle(toggle => !toggle)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self descriptive I guess. You need to use the setter instead of assigning a value directly to your state object.

Avoid this:

```
toggle = !toggle
```

Replace your onClick to not to re-assign:

```
onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
```

Comment: I am not sure why this question was closed ! Your answer was very helpful to me, as I was getting same error, and you told us not to use toggle = !toggle (which I was using)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
<button
  onClick={() => setToggle(prevToggle => !prevToggle)}
  className="navbar__toggler"
>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
</button>
```